# Cognitive Service API

Tags: machine-learning, azure-cognitive-services

I'm exploring the Azure Cognitive Service for one of our project. We had a Classified Community website called DewaList.com and this site is battling with spam. We had an Robotic Process Automation (RPA) that identify and remove the ads based on the listed spam keyword that we as human identify and marked as a spam.

Our next project is to generate intelligently  this spam keyword list using this Machine Learning. The logic is look at regularly new ads or a week or a month that coming through and if it's repetitive more than few time in a day or week. Then flagged that as a spam. The keyword will be based on phone number, website or email.

Can this be done  though via this Cognitive Service? What sort of API?

Any pointer that will be good for us as a starting point.

Thanks

Comment: For starter, you need a lot of data to train the model.

Comment: @koryakinp We had about 70,000+ active ads per year. Is that considering a lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're referring the Azure Machine Learning.

You have to configure the inputs to train you model, what did you configure? Below is the code - *I would configure div container with the placeholder as an input and co-relate that to your spam prediction*, by that I mean extract and feed that as your content to the engine

```
global inputs_dc, prediction_dc
inputs_dc = ModelDataCollector('model.pkl',identifier="inputs")
prediction_dc = ModelDataCollector('model.pkl', identifier="prediction")
```